# How can I create two tables in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to two tables in android but I see an error like does not found second table . How can I fixed?
is problem about database version or onCreate method I guess?

```
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME   = "DBO_Finish";
  private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
  private static final String TABLE_OLCUM = "olcum";
  private static final String TABLE_BILGI="asd";

  public dbHelper(Context context,Activity act) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS + 
            "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,user_name TEXT,user_password TEXT,olcum_id INTEGER" + ")";
      db.execSQL(sql);

      String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_BILGI + 
            "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,shortName TEXT,longName TEXT" + ")";
      db.execSQL(sql2);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_BILGI);

        onCreate(db);
  }
}
```

Comment: Uninstall your app. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Im using method below to create my table. if u want to modify table structure like adding field , first change ur class then , increase number of dbVersion in DatabaseHelper by one.
and new table will be created.

each table with specified class like this :

TblTest.java class for Tbltest :

public class TblTest {

```
    public static final String TABLE = "Test";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";


    public int id;

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table "
              + TABLE + "("
              + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key"
              + ");";
    }
```

and "DatabaseHelper.java" class for database helper (creating table):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DBNAME = "mytestdb";
    public SQLiteDatabase db; 
    private final static int dbVersion = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper() {
        super(AppContext.getAppContext(), DBNAME, null, dbVersion);
        open();
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          try {
              db.execSQL(TblTest.CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TblTest.TABLE);
          onCreate(db);
      }

      public void open() throws SQLException {

         db = getWritableDatabase();

      }

      public void close() {
          db.close();
      }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd argument of your constructor is a number indicating in which version of the DB are you. Basically every time you call your constructor with that number, the Android OS checks if there is already a DB with that version, if that's the case nothing more happens, but if the DB doesn't exists or the version registered to it is lower, then your `onUpgrade` method will be called.

So if you want to add new tables, simply **change that number to '2'** in this case, and increment it every time you want to create new tables.

Hope that helps, greetings!